# How to display the last six images from my webcam using PHP?

Tags: php, image, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get X newest files from a directory in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018080/how-to-get-x-newest-files-from-a-directory-in-php)
>   [Get most recent files recursively with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924433/get-most-recent-files-recursively-with-php)

I have a script receives the latest webcam image uploaded to www.bovicam/webcam:

```
<?php
$dir = 'webcam/';
$base_url = 'http://www.bovicam.com/webcam/';
$newest_mtime = 0;
$show_file = 'BROKEN';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..')) {
            $mtime = filemtime("$dir/$file");
            if ($mtime > $newest_mtime) {
                $newest_mtime = $mtime;
                $show_file = "$base_url/$file";
            }
        }
    }
}

print '<img src="' .$show_file. '" alt="Current Bovicam webcam image - views across        Bovisand Bay" style="width:90%; margin-top:7%; margin-bottom:3%;" class="displayed" id="webcam_image">';
?>
```

I want to display the last six images in the page below the webcam. I don't have the luxury of being able to 'label' the files from the camera by date, so is there a way to do this by 'last modified' as above?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Mario - so I'd have to work out a way to label the file names in order to do this?

Comment: So basically use a combination of `glob()` to get an array list, fetch the `filemtime()` for each, then cut out the first 6 from the array using `array_slice()`.

Comment: I'm pretty new to PHP Mario, is there anyway you may be able to provide an example?

Comment: I believe I can add sequential formatting to the file name, so 1, 2 3, etc, but I can't be specific in terms of date.