# Set limits to show txt files (from 5 files only) with phrase from directiory

Tags: php, count, limit, glob

I'm new at php but I want to create script to show me for example how many words are in txt files in a specify directory . But I want to choose from how many files I get the answer. In the directory are 20 files but I want my script to only show my words from 5 files (new files).

For now I have a script which shows words from all files in the directory.

I don't know how to set up limits. Could you help me?

```
$path_to_check = 'logs/';
$needle = 'error';
$tot = 0;
$numberOfFiles = 2;
foreach(glob($path_to_check . '*.txt') as $filename)
{
  foreach(file($filename) as $fli=>$fl)
  {
    if(strpos($fl, $needle)!==false)
    {
      $tot++;
      echo  '  <br> ' . $filename . '<br> line ' . ($fli+1) . ':<br> ' . $fl;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This post here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018080/how-to-get-x-newest-files-from-a-directory-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get X newest files from a directory in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018080/how-to-get-x-newest-files-from-a-directory-in-php)